# Почему скрипт выдает ошибку: "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

Имею скрипт и выглядит он так:

```
declare
    cursor activejobs is
        select 'begin dbms_scheduler.drop_job('''||JOB_name||''',force=>true); end;' as scr from dba_scheduler_running_jobs where job_name like '%NTFN%';    
begin
    for actjob in activejobs loop
        execute immediate actjob.scr;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

С точки зрения синтаксиса, все написано вроде верно, но мне выдает ошибку:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Tue Dec 24 17:21:23 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining,
Oracle Database Vault and Real Application Testing options

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

Вопрос, где я не прав? Второй день сижу, думаю.

Comment: Попробовал, не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 2):

> С точки зрения синтаксиса, все написано вроде верно, но мне выдает ошибку.

Сам анонимный блок синтактически верен и он компилируется. Но ошибка не в нём, а в том, что он запускает динамически - `ORA-06512: at line 6`, т.е в строчке:

```
execute immediate actjob.scr;
```

Для локализации ошибки надо как минимум вывести команду, которую блок будет выполнять.

Например, изменённый для воиспроизводимости блок из вопроса:

```
declare
    cursor activejobs is
        select 'begin dbms_scheduler.drop_job('''||JOB_name||''',force=>true); end;' scr 
        from (select 'XXX' JOB_name from dual);
begin
    for actjob in activejobs loop
        dbms_output.put_line ('>>'||actjob.scr||'<<');
        execute immediate actjob.scr;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

тоже выглядит синтактически правильно, но при выполнении ошибка:

```
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

В выводе видно, что в команде присутствует *non-ascii* символ:

```
>>begin???dbms_scheduler.drop_job('XXX',force=>true); end;<<
```

Поэтому, прежде всего стоит проверить скрипт на наличие *non-ascii* символoв:

```
$ grep -P "[^\x00-\x7F]" test.sql|xd
000000 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 73 65 6c 65 63 74 20 27  >        select '<
000010 62 65 67 69 6e e2 80 80 64 62 6d 73 5f 73 63 68  >begin...dbms_sch<
                      ^^^^^^^^
```